# How to detect amount of citation keys passed to custom cite command with biblatex and biber

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber, multiple-citations

I am working on using `biblatex+biber` flexibility and modularity to be able to create citation system to cite legal provisions (parts of laws, decrees and such). For that, I have created (crude) draft of custom datamodel, bibliography driver and now I am working on custom citation commands.

This sadly makes MWE quite lengthy.

I would like to know, if it is possible to detect number of *keys* passed to custom `cite` command, in order to change the output. Rules:

1. 1 *key*, no change
2. 2 *key*s, separate citations with  and text (example: `" and"`)
3. 3 *key*s, separate citations with *space* and *comma*
4. 4 or more *key*s, compress the citations to print in text body only first and last, others put only in bibliography

This is complet set of rules I would like to implement, but actually, if it is possible to detect number of *key*s passed to `cite` command, If anyone helping me with this would be kind to hint me how to proceed in no. 2, I happily implement No. 3 and 4 as excersize.

MWE:

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: biber
% arara: lualatex
% arara: biber
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass [a4paper, 11pt, twoside, openright, czech]{scrbook}          
\usepackage [czech,shorthands=off] {babel}                          
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}{speclegislation.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{speclegislation}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  dokument,
  zkracene,
  number,
  year,
  title,
  paragraf,
  odstavec,
  pismeno,
  sortkey,
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[speclegislation]{
  dokument,
  zkracene,
  number,
  year,
  title,
  paragraf,
  odstavec,
  pismeno,
  keywords,
  sortkey,
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber, datamodel=speclegislation, refsegment=chapter, defernumbers=true, mincrossrefs=1, backref=true, backrefstyle=three, sorting=none]{biblatex}

\newbibmacro{dokumentnumberyeartitle}{
  \printfield{dokument}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{number}%
  \newblock
  \printfield{year}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{title}
}

\newbibmacro{paragrafodstavecpismeno}{
  \printfield{paragraf} %
  \nopunct\newunit
  \printfield{odstavec} %
  \nopunct\newunit
  \printfield{pismeno}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{speclegislation}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{dokumentnumberyeartitle}
  \nopunct\newunit
  \usebibmacro{paragrafodstavecpismeno}
  \nopunct\newunit
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite=true]{
    \map{
      \pertype{speclegislation}
      \step[fieldsource=paragraf]
      \step[fieldset=sortkey, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{dokument}{#1\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{number}{#1/}
\DeclareFieldFormat{year}{#1\addnbspace Sb.,\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{paragraf}{§\addnbspace#1\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{odstavec}{odst.\addnbspace#1\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pismeno}{písm.\addnbspace#1)\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{zkracene}{#1\addspace}

\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{czech}{
  bibliography = {Reference},
}

\begin{filecontents}{citace.bib}
@speclegislation{v21p12pa,
paragraf = {12},
pismeno = {a},
keywords = {vyhlaska21},
crossref = {v21}
}

@speclegislation{v21p12pb,
paragraf = {12},
pismeno = {b},
keywords = {vyhlaska21},
crossref = {v21}
}

@speclegislation{v21p12pc,
paragraf = {12},
pismeno = {c},
keywords = {vyhlaska21},
crossref = {v21}
}

@speclegislation{v21p12pd,
paragraf = {12},
pismeno = {d},
keywords = {vyhlaska21},
crossref = {v21}
}

@speclegislation{v21p12pe,
paragraf = {12},
pismeno = {e},
keywords = {vyhlaska21},
crossref = {v21}
}

@speclegislation{v21p12pf,
paragraf = {12},
pismeno = {f},
keywords = {vyhlaska21},
crossref = {v21}
}

@speclegislation{v21,
dokument = {Vyhláška},
zkracene = {v.},
number = {21},
year = {2017},
title = {o zajišťování jaderné bezpečnosti JZ},
keywords = {vyhlaska21}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{citace.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{parvcite}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{paragrafodstavecpismeno}\printfield{zkracene}\printfield{number}\printfield{year}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
      \printfield{labelprefix}%
      \mkbibbrackets{\printfield{labelnumber}}}%
     }
    {\addcomma\addspace}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycite}{ O{} O{} m }{
\parvcite{#3}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Citation testing:

Current output:

1 \textit{key} citation:
\mycite{v21p12pa}

\medskip

2 \textit{keys} citation

\mycite{v21p12pa, v21p12pb}

Desired output:

\mycite{v21p12pa} and \mycite{v21p12pb}

\medskip

3 \textit{key} citation:

\mycite{v21p12pa, v21p12pb, v21p12pc}

Desired output:

\mycite{v21p12pa}, \mycite{v21p12pb}, \mycite{v21p12pc}

\medskip

4 or more \textit{key}s citation:

\mycite{v21p12pa, v21p12pb, v21p12pc, v21p12pd}

Desired output:

\mycite{v21p12pa} \nocite{v21p12pb} \nocite{v21p12pc} – \mycite{v21p12pd}

\clearpage

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

PS: Text is partly in czech, I hope it doesnt mind. Also, `mycite` command is "prepared" to be more complicated/intricate, thats why it is defined with `xparse` and with 2 optional and 1 mandatory argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex` stores the number of entry keys cited in the current invocation of `\...cite` in `citetotal` and the number of the current key in `citecount`. With these two counters you should be able to implement what you want.

Note that there are also `multicitetotal` and `multicitecount` to counter the number of entry key groups in the multi-cite commands `\...cites`.

`biblatex` provides the tests `\iffirstcitekey{<true>}{<false>}` and `\iflastcitekey{<true>}{<false>}` out of the box, so you don't have to write a number comparison test for these common cases, but I will not use the two commands in the example below.

The following MWE demonstrates how `citecount` and `citetotal` can be used in a simplified setting.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newcommand*{\mycitedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{citetotal}}{2}
    {\addcomma\space}
    {\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}}

\newbibmacro*{mycite}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
       test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}}
    or test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}}
    or test {\ifnumless{\value{citetotal}}{4}}}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printfield{labelprefix}%
       \printfield{labelnumber}%
       \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
         {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
         {}}}
    {}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{mycite}}
  {\setunit{\mycitedelim}}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
\mycite{sigfridsson}

\mycite{sigfridsson,nussbaum}

\mycite{sigfridsson,nussbaum,worman}

\mycite{sigfridsson,nussbaum,worman,geer}

\mycite{sigfridsson,nussbaum,worman,geer,cicero}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [4]//[4 and 3]//[4, 3, 5]//[4, 2]//[4, 1]]

Note that if you want proper compression of your citations, you need something more intricate that actually checks whether the output labels can be compressed (you can compress "12a, 12b, 12c, 12d" to "12a-12d" or "12a-d", but you can't compress "12a, 12b, 14a, 14e" to "12a-14e" or "12a-e"). This is done in [`numeric-comp.cbx`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/master/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric-comp.cbx) for simple label numbers, but in your use case it may be quite a bit more complex.

Comment: I absolutely agree about your note to proper compression. For that, I am considering use of key-value interface for the custom citation command *or* using `multicites` *or* using specific citation sets. Now, this implementation is for me as a user and proof of concept for my boss and collegues, that there are much better performing interfaces than word (duh ...) I solve as much as I can with my current knowledge and with suggestions you have mentioned, I am pretty much confident that I can solve most of the issues of my use-case.